# IIS causing high SQL processes load in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, process, transactions

I use SQL Server 2016 edition. I have a web server which runs IIS. 
Sometimes, during the day, iis causes so much sql server processes unexpectedly. When i execute sp_Who3 procedure, i see so many resul set higher than it should be. For example, my db transactions should be around 45 - 80. But, instantly it goes up to above 400. What can cause this issue? How can i troubleshoot for this problem?

When i reseted iis server, database returns to the normal value. But, after several minitues like 10 or 15 minutes the problem happens again.

sp_Who3 open source procedure

No error message. Just high numbers of sql processes.

Comment: Is your website open to the public? Perhaps a DDOS attack? You should be looking at your network traffic and seeing where it's all coming from.

Comment: Perhaps queries in your workload are in need of query and index tuning. A high number of concurrent queries may be a symptom.

Comment: @DanGuzman It has occured since last week but every day. There is a store procedure which the web application uses most. Should i optimize the store procedure?

Comment: @Omer, that is the first step I suggest. View the execution plan for query and index tuning opportunities.

Comment: @DanGuzman Ok. What should be other steps? Where should i check if the problem goes on?

Comment: @Omer, if the problem continues after tuning, it may be the database server is undersized for the workload or an application design issue. We can only speculate without details. If you need help with query and index tuning, [upload the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. Table DDL with indexes may also be helpful.

Comment: @DanGuzman Hi again. I uploaded the execution plan. You can access it from this link https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkMmlBzeH . If you can check it out, i will be appreciated.

Comment: @Omer, it looks like that plan is for several `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements rather than plans for actual proc execution. Use this query to get one of the proc cached plans and stats from cache, ideally when you are experiencing the issue: `SELECT ps.execution_count, ps.total_elapsed_time, ps.total_logical_reads, ps.total_worker_time, qp.query_plan FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS ps CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ps.plan_handle) AS qp WHERE ps.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Netone2004.dbo.n1w_get_technical_setup_support_list') AND ps.database_id = DB_ID(N'Netone2004');`